# WebRTC unable to decode text message sent from Datachannel

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to use WebRTC datachannel for the first time. I can sent text using WebRTC javascript code, and can catch the event from my WebRTC android code.

I am following procedure :

```
From JavaScript client :  
         function sendMsg(msg){
                if(dataChannel.readyState=="open"){
                    dataChannel.send(msg); //dataChannel = my datachannel object
                }
                else{
                    console.error("data channel no ready");
                }
            }

From WebRTC android client: 
        public void onMessage(final Buffer arg0) {
            byte[] bytearr = new byte[arg0.data.remaining()];
            //Case 1:
            Log.e("MSG_GOT",arg0.data.get(bytearr).toString());
            //Case 2:
            Log.e("MSG_GOT " + arg0.data.toString()); 
        }
```

For case 1 :
   I am getting some unreadable data, which I assume is encoded. 
For case 2:
   I am getting an object as java.nio.ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer, status: capacity=6 position=6 limit=6 .
   I was sending abcdef as text.

How can I decode this into readable text ? Or is there any function provided by WebRTC android api to decode it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following function, that works when I send String payloads.

```
public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {
            ByteBuffer data = buffer.data;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[data.remaining()];
            data.get(bytes);
            final String message = new String(bytes);

            // ...
        }
```

I remember it is from a similar question/answer which I cannot find right now.